# HTML - how to insert rows in a prepend manner?

Tags: javascript, html, prepend

I'm trying to add a new set of rows below the original one's and have a delete function together w/ the add function. Luckily I bumped into an article of w3schools : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

However it adds the new cells above the original one's, how can I tweak it to make it work?

CODE:

```
<table id="myTable" border="1">
<tr>
<td>Row1 cell1</td>
<td>Row1 cell2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row2 cell1</td>
<td>Row2 cell2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Row3 cell1</td>
<td>Row3 cell2</td>
</tr>
</table><br>

<button onclick="myCreateFunction()">Create row</button>
<button onclick="myDeleteFunction()">Delete row</button>

<script>
function myCreateFunction()
{
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  {
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
  cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
  }
}
function myDeleteFunction()
{
document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(0);
}
</script>
```

Comment: There is no jQuery here, should you have tagged it?

Comment: No, I've to correct you. You sadly bumped into an article by w3schools. http://www.w3fools.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var row = table.insertRow(0); // 0 represent the 0th index and hence it add at top
```

change it to

```
var tdsLength = table.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
var row = table.insertRow(tdsLength);  //change it to last index
```

or

```
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
```

From [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.insertRow), If index is `-1` or equal to the number of rows, the row is appended as the last row. 
[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LdZX9/)

Comment: sir it worked fine, just waiting for a few minues to checked it as the correct answer, an added question in the delete part it still deletes the upper ones instead of the ones below, does it follow the same logic?

Comment: @SOS yes my friend.  still the index within deleteRow is`0` and therefore it deletes the topmost element, change it to `-1` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LdZX9/1/))

Answer (score 2):

[`insertRow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.insertRow) takes the position of the new row as an (optional) parameter. So, if you want the new row at the end of the table, insert an according index like this:

```
var row = table.insertRow( table.rows.length );
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/86r3j/)

In your code you set an index of `0`, which by definition is the first row.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the jQuery solution.... if you want it.

**HTML**

```
<table border="1" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Col 1</td>
            <td>Col 2</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<input type="button" onclick="addRow()" value="Add row" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var rowNo = 1;
function addRow()
{
    $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr><td>Row #'+ rowNo +'</td>'+
                               '<td>Row #'+ rowNo +'</td></tr>');
    rowNo++;    
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fWq9x/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery then use `.after()` with `:eq(int)` and for removing you can use `.remove()` but if you want to remove only newly added rows then you can use `:gt(int)` method:

```
$(function () {
   $('#create').on('click', function () {
      var table = $('#myTable')[0];
      var rows = table.rows.length;
      var row = '<tr><td>'+ rows +'</td><td>'+ rows +'</td></tr>';
      $('#myTable').find('tr:eq(2)').after(row);
   });
   $('#delete').on('click', function () {
      $('#myTable').find('tr:gt(2)').get(0).remove();
   });
});
```

---

Using the above script you have to give your buttons specific ids `#create` for row creation and `#delete` for delete button like suggested below.

```
<button id='create'>Create row</button>
<button id='delete'>Delete row</button>
```

---

#### Note:

Unobtrusive javascript is better. Inline scripting should be avoided.

#### [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5HF2r/1/)

---

### Updates:

Instead of hardCode in `:eq(2) and :gt(2)` we can cache the length of the trs in table:

```
$(function () {
   var o = $('#myTable').find('tr:last').index(); // cache it here
   $('#create').on('click', function () {
      var table = $('#myTable')[0];
      var rows = table.rows.length;
      var row = '<tr><td>' + rows + '</td><td>' + rows + '</td></tr>';
      $('#myTable').find('tr:eq(' + o + ')').after(row); // place it here
   });
   $('#delete').on('click', function () {
      $('#myTable').find('tr:gt(' + o + ')').get(0).remove(); // and here
   });
});
```

#### [Demo fiddle with cached trs](http://jsfiddle.net/5HF2r/2/)

---

`$('#myTable').find('tr:last').index();` this line gets the last tr's index at the dom ready which is in this case `2` because `.index()` is `0` based.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code in:

```
var row = table.insertRow(0);
```

to:

```
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use **jQuery .prepend() function**? Check it here: http://api.jquery.com/prepend/